# This class is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields are not final:

Tags: class, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, setstate

If I am declaring the variables as final then the values(variables) I want to change(on pressed) are in `setState(){}` so those variables can be changed What to do to prevent this?

Also, why is it written `widget.value`?

I have tried using static instead of final doesn't work

```
class BottomCard extends StatefulWidget {

String title;

int value;
@override
_BottomCardState createState() => _BottomCardState(); }

class _BottomCardState extends State<BottomCard> {..... 


....<Widget>[  
        FloatingActionButton(
          elevation: 0,
          child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.plus),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              widget.value++;
            });
          },
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF47535E),
        ),
```

Answer (score 11):

If you don't need to get variables (title & value) from outside your widget, you can declare them in the `_BottomCardState` class and use them as you want, for example:

```
class BottomCardState extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomCardStateState createState() => _BottomCardStateState();
}

class _BottomCardStateState extends State<BottomCardState> {
  int _value;
  String title;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _value = 0;
    title = "any thing";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        elevation: 0,
        child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.plus),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _value++; // increment value here
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

If you need to get variables (value & title) from other class, then you need to:

1. Mark them as final, or
2. Get them from constructor

To access their values in `_BottomCardStateState`, you can access them using `widget._value`. They are final so you can't modify them. For example:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: BottomCardState(2,"some thing"),
    );
  }
}

class BottomCardState extends StatefulWidget {
  final int _value;
  final String title;
  BottomCardState(this._value,this.title)

  @override
  _BottomCardStateState createState() => _BottomCardStateState();
}

class _BottomCardStateState extends State<BottomCardState> {
  int value ;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    value = widget._value ;
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        elevation: 0,
        child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.plus),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
          value++; // increment value here
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> If I am declaring the variables as final then then the values(variables) i want to change(on pressed) are in set state(){} so those variables can be changed What to do to prevent this?

Extend `StatefulWidget`.

> Also why is it written widget.value?

This means you are accessing `value` in your `StatefulWidget` subclass and this value is actually defined in your `State` class.

---

Full code should look like:

```
class BottomCardState extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomCardStateState createState() => _BottomCardStateState();
}

class _BottomCardStateState extends State<BottomCardState> {
  int _value = 0; // set value here

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        elevation: 0,
        child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.plus),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _value++; // increment value here
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just added this line top of the error class.

```
//ignore: must_be_immutable
```